# How devise methods are available in ApplicationController.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is `ApplicationController` inherits from `DeviseController`?
   Otherwise how devise methods are available in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: What kind of `devise` method available in `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Not only in ApplicationCOntroller, but available in all controllers. And methods i am talking about are user_signed_in? and current_user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::Base`, which
>   defines a number of helpful methods.
>   [`ref`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions)

`Devise::Controller` has a several modules that's hooked up in to [`ActionController` on_load](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7b33a8ef5749e0b593d785a1cd4787d2979cdee5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L132).

For example the [`Devise::Controller::Helpers`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7b33a8ef5749e0b593d785a1cd4787d2979cdee5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) module defines and loads helpers below:

```
  #   Generated methods:
  #     authenticate_user!  # Signs user in or redirect
  #     authenticate_admin! # Signs admin in or redirect
  #     user_signed_in?     # Checks whether there is a user signed in or not
  #     admin_signed_in?    # Checks whether there is an admin signed in or not
  #     current_user        # Current signed in user
  #     current_admin       # Current signed in admin
  #     user_session        # Session data available only to the user scope
  #     admin_session       # Session data available only to the admin scope
  #
  #   Use:
  #     before_action :authenticate_user!  # Tell devise to use :user map
  #     before_action :authenticate_admin! # Tell devise to use :admin map
```

Comment: Turned out that this is the **only correct answer**. The remaining answers from other users are terribly wrong!

Answer (score 0):

No, `ApplicationController` is the base, like the name, is the controller for the all application.

`ApplicationController` is extended from `DeviseController`.

Comment: ApplicationController extends DeviseController and also ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::Base.  It looks like multiple inheritance?  is DeviseController a Module then?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationController` doesn't inherit from `DeviceController`. `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::Base`. In ApplicationController the method you talking about `configure_permitted_parameters` is used with before_filter which is callback.

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :remember_me) }
end
```

Comment: How about helpers like `authenticate_user!` or `current_user`?

Comment: `module Helpers
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern` using the helper module. You will see `Devise::Controller` has a several modules that's hooked up in to `ActionController` `on_load`.

Answer (score 0):

No , Application Controller doesn't inherits from Devise controller.It is the base.To use devise methods in it, you can use the below:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name, :is_active]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << [:user_name]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name,:username,:is_active]

  end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  "some path"
end
```